# Generic react component (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to stop all properties that are not specified with generics. Whit this code both TestTheButton and TestTheButtonGenerics runs fine. I need TestTheButton go give error in this case.

```
import React from 'react';

export type ButtonProps<GenericProps = never> = GenericProps & {
    
}

const Button: <T>(
    p: ButtonProps<T>
) => React.ReactElement<ButtonProps<T>> = ({  ...rest }) => {
    return <button {...rest} >Click me!</button>;
};

// I would like to throw and error her
export const TestTheButton = () => {
    return <Button test={false}/>
};

// should work like this. To pass extra props you need to define the Generic
export const TestTheButtonGenerics = () => {
    return <Button <{test: boolean;}> test={true}/>
};
```

Comment: If I'm reading right, what you're describing is disabling TypeScript's generic type argument inference. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is that. If you want to pass extra props, you need to pass it as a generic. The Button component here is used by many teams using different versions of react-router. The to attribute is different in version 5 compared to 6 so that must be generic and cant be part of default Button api. I was thinking
<Button <LinkProps> to="url" attributeDefinedInButtonNotLinkProps="green" />.

Comment: I believe it worth using tagged union types or something like that rather than require to use explicit generic parameter. It sounds for me as an antipattern. But, this is only my opinion, we all have different approach, right?

Comment: @pethel - `TestTheButton` **is** passing in a generic argument, just an inferred one based on the value rather than an explicit one. I think I'm with VLAZ: A discriminated union seems like a good way to go. Or even separate components (with reuse of the implementation).

Comment: Thanks @captain-yossarian
The problem with tagged union types and so is that I do not want the Button to know anything about react-router. Its a shared library and I do not want to add the dependency there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder
can I do anything about the inferred one. The problem here is that I do not want my Button to know anything about react-router. Maybe other teams use other solutions?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how you can disable type argument inference (if you even can).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure it is even possible, if you provide an argument, generic type is infered automatically

Comment: @captain-yossarian - That's what I suspected. :-)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help guys. I hope you saw the problem I was trying to solve at least :)

Comment: One more thing, return type of Button `React.ReactElement<ButtonProps<T>>` does not make sense. TS does not support it. React component always have `JSX.Element` or other wide type. Return type of react component can't depend on generic